# Record audio in Google App Engine using rtmplite?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rtmp

I am in the process of building a Google App Engine application which requires audio to be recorded and saved in our database. I have found no alternative to using some form of RTMP server for recording audio through flash, so [rtmplite] (http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) came into our horizon.

Since I have no experience with rtmplite, is it the right choice for our project? Or is there any other Python-based RTMP solution that allows audio recording? Any flash client you can recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a flash app that just records the sound locally, then uploads it in a standard HTTP POST request?

Comment: Like @Nick Johnson said you can use a flash app to upload your audio to server and you can persist into datastore as a blob.

Comment: I didn't choose Flash because my Flash experience is very limited and I'm the only programmer for the project. Right now I'm trying Java Applet. So far it works great.

Answer (score 5):

Google App Engine is tricky for RTMP because it does not support sockets. You would have to use something like RTMPT which is tunneled over HTTP, however, this tunneling incurs latency so if you are looking to do anything realtime this could become an issue.

Currently rtmplite does not support RTMPT so this would not be possible at the moment. I am involved in a project, RTMPy (http://rtmpy.org), that is planning support for RTMPT and AppEngine. Unfortunately AppEngine support is probably a few months out.

Comment: Any progress on AppEngine support for RTMPy?

Answer (score 0):

Try appengine backends, they currently don't whitelist a lot of things required for such streaming. But they might soon do so. Once they enable sockets, then rtmplite or rtmpy could easily be ported to run there. Backends already support unlimited request length which is required for streaming.